# how could you get indication that a the stream started? (AKKA)

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have a function that is in charge of running my stream, it looks like this:

```
  def runGraph(sharedKillSwitch: SharedKillSwitch = sharedKillSwitch): NotUsed = {
    logger.info(s"Starting Stream")
    graph(
      source = RestartSource.withBackoff(RestartSettings(3.second, 5.minutes, 0.2))(() => SqsSource(inboundQueueURL, SqsSourceSettings().withMessageAttribute(MessageAttributeName("All")))(sqsConfig.client)),
      sink = SqsAckSink(inboundQueueURL)(sqsConfig.client),
      switch = sharedKillSwitch
    ).run()
  }
```

`graph` is another function that is construction the graph and returning `RunnableGraph[NotUsed]`.

Now I want call runGraph and then to do something else, but it seams its not Async call so I can't map it and wait for the stream to start...

how could you get indication that a the stream started?

Comment: The stream starts when `run` is called. Are you interested to know when the first element has passed through the graph?

Comment: @TomerShetah so ```run``` cannot fail? I want to update something in the database when  I know safely that the stream is running..

Comment: It shouldn't fail. But you can always wrap a code with try/catch, and move the `starting stream` log to be after `run()` is called.

Comment: @user804968 `run` won't fail but there still may be a fault when processing an element in the stream. It's not clear what kind of warranty you need.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to take advantage of `Source.lazySource` which runs the callback once downstream requests elements. This source can be `prepend` to the `SqsSource` and act as the first element/s in the stream.

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source/lazySource.html

> Defers creation and materialization of a Source until there is demand, then emits the elements from the source downstream just like if it had been created up front.

```
def runGraph(sharedKillSwitch: SharedKillSwitch = sharedKillSwitch): Promise[Done] = {
    logger.info(s"Starting Stream")
    
    val streamStarted = Promise[Done]
    
    graph(
        source = RestartSource.withBackoff(RestartSettings(3.second, 5.minutes, 0.2))({ () => 
            SqsSource(inboundQueueURL, SqsSourceSettings()
                .withMessageAttribute(MessageAttributeName("All")))(sqsConfig.client)
                .prepend(Source.lazySource({ () =>
                    streamStarted.trySuccess(Done)
                    Source.empty
                }))
        }),
        sink = SqsAckSink(inboundQueueURL)(sqsConfig.client),
        switch = sharedKillSwitch
    )
    .run()

    streamStarted
}
```

Note: this solution only tells you that the stream has started AT LEAST ONCE (it could restart due to `RestartSource`). You can also track stream closure by adding a sink which tracks if the stream has currently completed and update some shared state to reflect this.